# Counting inconsistent answers

Tags: excel

Having the following table:

[image]

In columns a,b,c,d i have points and in column two i want to point to a column with a biggest number.I want to count how many times a letter in column "2" is wrong i.e. points to number of points smaller than the biggest number in this row e.g. in this table formula should return two. As there are two inconsistent answers.

I want to relay on formula only. I would prefer not to use any additional columns and rows.

Still trying to find a solution without use of additional columns or rows.

Comment: You'll have to create a column next to your "2" column (assumed to be the E column in the provided formula) that has the actual correct answers and compares those against what's in the "2" column using this formula: `=E2=INDEX(A$1:D$1,MATCH(MAX(A2:D2),A2:D2,0))`  And then do a COUNTIF on the helper column for FALSE results to get the total count of incorrect answers

Comment: What if i do not want to have an additional column?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this without a helper column unless you use VBA to create a UDF.  If preferred, you could hide the helper column, or put it on a hidden worksheet

Comment: Maybe this could be done with use of arrays or not?

Comment: Even with array formulas, I can't think of a way to do this without a helper column

Comment: Nevertheless thank you very much!

Comment: two, "2", two, two - is there a worse way to choose column headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with array formulae: I have just learned about the possibilities of using OFFSET so this is my try at using it to produce an array of rows, finding the maximum of each row and comparing it to the cell given by the letter:-

```
=SUM(--(N(OFFSET(A1,{0;1;2},CODE(F1:F3)-97))<>SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(A1,{0;1;2},0,,4))))
```

It is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

I am assuming the numbers are in A1:D3 and the letters are in F1:F3.

Comment: I was just about there.  I was missing the `N`: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(N(OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:D4)-ROW(A2),CODE(E2:E4)-97,1))<>SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(A2:D4,ROW(A2:D4)-ROW(A2),0,1))))`

Comment: Yes, you have taken a bit more time to make it more general without hard-coding the row numbers. I think N is my favourite function!

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the output was exactly "a", "b", "c", "d", etc?  Aren't those just variables for what the output could be (the actual header names)?

Comment: I think you could change it to match with the header names if they were not literally "a", "b" etc. using MATCH(A1:D1,F1:F3,0)

Comment: No that was the wrong way round, the whole formula matching the headers in A1:D1 would be =SUM(--(N(OFFSET(A2,{0;1;2},MATCH(F2:F4,A1:D1,0)))<>SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(A2,{0;1;2},0,,4))))